# How to grep all value starting with "sg" in my case

Tags: sed, grep

So i have this .txt file like this

```
TAGS    aws:cloudformation:stack-name   yanka-cloudformer
TAGS    aws:cloudformation:logical-id   WebServerSecurityGroup
SECURITYGROUPS  launch-wizard-3 created 2017-04-11T15:51:41.918+09:00   sg-77aaaa10     an-dx-trainning     vpc-878311e3
SECURITYGROUPS  This security group was generated by AWS Marketplace and is based on recommended settin s for CentOS 6 (x86_64) - with Updates HVM version 6 2014-09-29 provided by Centos.org  sg-7842031d     CentOS 6 -x86_64- - with Updates HVM-6 2014-09-29-AutogenByAWSMP-       270062507952    vpc-11d10f74
SECURITYGROUPS  from other cloud        sg-796d1b1e     rancher-demo-sg 270062507952    vpc-b4ef99d1
SECURITYGROUPS  default VPC security group      sg-79a4861d     Cfn-Vpc-Sg-temp-SecurityGroup2DefaultSG-JLBXQ8YG4RN5    270062507952    vpc-ded6c7bb
USERIDGROUPPAIRS        sg-79a4861d     270062507952
```

I just want to grep all value start with "sg" only which is **sg-xxxxxx**. How can i do that?

I tried this but what got a long list of sg.

```
cat hello.txt | grep -o "sg*"
sg
sg
sg
sg
```

I want to get every value started with "sg"

Like this:

```
sg-77aaaa10
sg-796d1b1e 
sg-79a4861d
```

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ grep -o 'sg-[^ ]*' ip.txt
sg-77aaaa10
sg-7842031d
sg-796d1b1e
sg-79a4861d
sg-79a4861d
```

- `[^ ]*` means other than space character. You can also use `[0-9a-f]` if you know they consist of only hex characters
- pipe it to `sort -u` or `sort | uniq` or `awk '!seen[$0]++'` to remove duplicates

`sg*` means match `s` followed by `g` zero or more times